# get a value from lookup field in crm 2015 using javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2015

i can get the id of the contact but who i get the email of this contact ?????

```
function getdata(){
var entityName, entityId, entityLabel, lookupFieldObject;

    // parentaccountid is the lookup field name that we try to reach its values
    lookupFieldObject = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get('mbmhr_employee');
    if (lookupFieldObject.getValue() != null) {
        entityId = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].id;
        entityName = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].entityType;
        entityLabel = lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].name;

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("mbmhr_test22").setValue(entityLabel );    

    }    
}
```

Comment: This is really really helpful! I was looking for that all day. The `lookupFieldObject.getValue()[0].name` _will_ return the input value of the field upon validate and loss of focus!

Answer (score 1):

You need to query the server for additional details of related records.

Have a look at [Getting started with CRM 2011 JavaScript REST (OData) Web Service Calls](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/getting-started-with-crm-2011-javascript-rest-odata-web-service-calls/) and [Retrieve Data using OData queries with Javascript in CRM 2013](http://mehmetgunen.com/retrieve-data-using-odata-queries-with-javascript-in-crm-2013/) to get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

OData endpoint, once again, to the rescue:

```
var contactId = null;
try { contactId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('mbmhr_employee').getValue()[0].id; } catch(ex) { contactId = null; }
if(contactId !== null)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet(guid'" + contactId + "')?$select=EMailAddress1";
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState == 4){
            var data = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
            // use data.d.EmailAddress1 
        }
    };
    req.send(null);
}
```